# Difference in lighting between "file -> save as" and "saveas"

Tags: matlab, save, figure, lighting

I am rendering some 3D mesh using `trimesh` and then apply some lighting. I then save my file via

```
saveas(gcf,'test.png')
```

The saved image's lighting does not resemble the one of the image on screen. However, when I go to the file menu and choose "save as" and save as a png, the image looks fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1PT49C/index.html?product=SL&solution=1-1PT49C&nocookie=true). Turns out there is another function that is called when you do "file -> save as"